# Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message Endpoint handler details: rabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

This is my listener code. When I run it on the server, rabbitmq is showing as consumer count as 1 but in the console, it is showing a below error
Please find the below error and help me to solve this.

***org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message ***

-Endpoint handler details:

-Method [public void com.example.demo.RabbitMQConsumer.getMessage(byte[]) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Bean [com.example.demo.RabbitMQConsumer@591579f1]

```
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:193) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1547) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) ~[spring-rabb***
```

````
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RabbitMQConsumer {

    /*
     * @RabbitListener(queues = "Mobile") public void getMessage(Person p) {
     * System.out.println(p.getName()); }
     */

    @RabbitListener(queues = "Mobile")
    public void getMessage(byte[] message) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(message);
        ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        Person p = (Person) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        bis.close();
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }

}``` **RabbitMQ server is running on port:15672**
````

Comment: what is that error

Comment: Could you please show us the error you had?

Comment: @Rookie007 **org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message *

-Endpoint handler details:

-Method [public void com.example.demo.RabbitMQConsumer.getMessage(byte[]) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Bean [com.example.demo.RabbitMQConsumer@591579f1]

at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:193) ~[spring-rabbit- **